# Change Keycloak server login theme in Wildfly Swarm

Tags: keycloak, wildfly-swarm

I'we created uber Wildfly-Swarm jar with included Keycloak Server in [WildFly Swarm Project Generator](http://wildfly-swarm.io/generator/).

Everything runs fine but the problem comes when I want to add my custum theme,

I have read official [manual](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/server_development/topics/themes.html) for creating themes but here is nothing describing how to do this inside Wildfly-Swarm's uber jar. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think that's a known issue at present, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM-989

Comment: Hi Kiki!

Have you been able to solve this? I'm having the same question, I cannot find any documentation about this.

Comment: No I was not able to solve this.